# Can't show the core data in tableview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
class showPageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  
{

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var records : [Record] = []

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return records.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    if editingStyle == .delete{
        let record = records[indexPath.row]
        context.delete(record)
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
        do{
            records = try context.fetch(Record.fetchRequest())
        } catch{
            print("Failed")
        }
    }


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    getData()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func getData(){
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    do{
        records = try context.fetch(Record.fetchRequest())
    } catch{
        print("123")
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Hello everyone, I just tried to show the core data in table view, I already connect the `dataSource` and `delegate` to the `ViewController`, and I confirmed There are some data in core data, anyone can help me plz? thanks

Comment: no, i can build the app and simulate it , but just show nothing

Answer (score 0):

Two big mistakes:

1. You cannot create a cell with the default initializer `UITableViewCell()` you have to dequeue it.
2. You have to get the item in the data source array for the index path and assign a value of a property to a label of the cell.

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
       let record = records[indexPath.row]
       cell.textLabel!.text = record.<nameOfProperty>
       return cell
   }
   ```

`cell` is the identifier specified in Interface Builder.
`<nameOfProperty>` is a property in your data model.