# Invisible trouble to view the Core Data in TableViewCells

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-data, swift3

Did from the example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3d4jY23eLOoejdRWkE0SG1VMkk

Step 1. I implemented the Core Data "Database". I have now 17 record and want to view all of them through the Cells in TableView ...  [image]

I did as like it was in tutorial, but it doesn't work. I wasted a week, and can't find an error :( It loads perfectly, but data is not displayed in cells :( So...

```js
import Foundation
import CoreData

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class DatabaseController
{
    private init() { }
    
class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext
{
    return persistentContainer.viewContext
}
    
// MARK: - Core Data stack
static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer =
{
    let container = NSPersistentContainer.init(name: "Database")
    //let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Database")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError?
        {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
    
// MARK: - Core Data Saving support
class func saveContext ()
{
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges
        {
            do {
                try context.save()
            }
            catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
}
    
}
```

Mainly 3 files ... save/get/persistant container in "DatabaseController.swift"
Next "AppDelegate.Swift"...

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)
{
    DatabaseController.saveContext()
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL =
{
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel =
{
    let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Database", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? =
{
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Database.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

    do
    {
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
    }
    catch {
        coordinator = nil

        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        let error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict as? [AnyHashable : Any])
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(String(describing: error)), \(error.userInfo)")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        abort()
    }
    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? =
{
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil
    {
        return nil
    }

    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

Main functions responsible for DataCore
And final file for TableView. Before i made it as DataCore , cells were displayed like this

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "ENTP")
            cell.postTitleLabel.text = "ENTP"
            cell.authorLabel.text = "Oleksandr Zheliezniak"
            cell.authorImageView.image = UIImage(named: "author"):
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "INTJ")
            cell.postTitleLabel.text = "INTJ"
            cell.authorLabel.text = "Gabriel Theodoropoulos"
            cell.authorImageView.image = UIImage(named: "appcoda-300")
        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "ENTP")
            cell.postTitleLabel.text = "ENTJ"
            cell.authorLabel.text = "Gabriel Theodoropoulos"
            cell.authorImageView.image = UIImage(named: "appcoda-300")
        } else {
            cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "СеКс")
            cell.postTitleLabel.text = "и виски"
            cell.authorLabel.text = "Кокс Карибский))"
            cell.authorImageView.image = UIImage(named: "appcoda-300")
        }
```

Final file as below:

```
//
//  PersonTableViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Oleksandr Z 2017(c).
//
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreData

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class PersonTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
{
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: Any)
    {
        switchScreen()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!
    let moc: NSManagedObjectContext? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>?
    var valueToPass:String!
    //override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {return true}

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // MARK: - CORE DATA fetching out to the TableView
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: IdentitiesFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: self.moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        do
        {
            try fetchedResultsController?.performFetch()
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
        }

        //Visualization
        if self.revealViewController() != nil
        {
            self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 250
            self.revealViewController().frontViewShadowRadius = 10
            self.revealViewController().frontViewShadowColor = UIColor.black
            self.revealViewController().frontViewShadowOpacity = 1

            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = true
    }

    func IdentitiesFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>
    {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Identity")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastModified", ascending: true)

        fetchRequest.predicate = nil
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        do
        {
            try fetchedResultsController?.performFetch()
        }
        catch
        {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
        }

        return fetchRequest
    }

    //MARK: NSFetchedResultsController Delegate Functions
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {    }

        switch editingStyle
        {
        case .delete:
            do
            {
                moc?.delete(fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) as! Identity)
                try moc?.save()
            }
            catch
            {
                print(error)
            }
        case .insert:
            break
        case .none:
            break
        }

    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?)
    {
        switch type
        {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.insert:
            tableView.insertRows(at: NSArray(object: newIndexPath!) as! [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.delete:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: NSArray(object: indexPath!) as! [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.move:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: NSArray(object: indexPath!) as! [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
            tableView.insertRows(at: NSArray(object: newIndexPath!) as! [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
            break
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.update:
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath! as IndexPath)
            break
            //default:
            //    break
        }
    }

    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)
    {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)
    {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?.count ?? 0
    }

    //Detailed viewCell
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
        /*
         // Get Cell Label
         let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
         let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

         valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel?.text
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegueIdentifer", sender: self)
         */
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "ShowPerson")
        {
            //var viewController = segue.destination as! PersonDetailViewController
            //viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as!PersonTableViewCell

        if let cellContact = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) as? Identity
        {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(String(describing: cellContact.pName)), \(String(describing: cellContact.lastModified))"
        }

        let identityClassName:String = String(describing: Identity.self)
        //let typeClassName:String     = String(describing: Type.self)
        let identity:Identity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: identityClassName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! Identity
        //let type:Type = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: typeClassName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! Type

        let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Identity> = Identity.fetchRequest()
        do
        {
            let searchResults = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
            print("number of results: \(searchResults.count)")
            for result in searchResults as [Identity]
            {
                print("\(result.pName!) is \(result.accuracy)% Robesper. Updeted \(result.lastModified!).")

                cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "ENTP")
                cell.postTitleLabel.text = identity.pName
                cell.authorLabel.text = identity.imType
                cell.authorImageView.image = UIImage(named: "author")
            }
        }
        catch   { print("Error: \(error)") }

        return cell
    }

    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to toIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    }

    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }

    func switchScreen()
    {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let vc : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PersonDetail") as UIViewController
        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Tried solution: [Can't show the core data in tableview Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189170/cant-show-the-core-data-in-tableview-swift) but it didn't help. Tried all similar topics but can't solve the problem.

Comment: This would be a good time to learn how to use Xcode's debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var identities : [Identity] = []

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
```

I tried a lot. There is no matter which solution to use (extensions,lazy,direct).

You should create two variables fore sure : ONE for all data array; SECOND for single data in array.

That is the way how it works basically:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as!PersonTableViewCell

    let identity = identities[indexPath.row]

            cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: <picture name>)
            cell.postTitleLabel.text = identity.<Your attribute of entity>
            cell.authorLabel.text = identity.<Your attribute of entity>
            cell.authorImageView.image = UIImage(named: <picture name>)

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two separate CoreData stacks: one set up by the `DatabaseController` class, which uses the `viewContext` from a `NSPersistentContainer` (introduced in iOS10), and another set up in the AppDelegate, which uses what looks like standard boilerplate from the older project templates.  Your FRC uses the latter, whilst the rest of your code uses the former.

Although these seem to use the same model file, I suspect they are using different persistent stores.  I think if you change this line:

```
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: IdentitiesFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: self.moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
```

to:

```
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: IdentitiesFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: DatabaseController.getContext(), sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
```

your FRC will be using the same context as the code that creates objects, so you should see some results.  There are other problems with your code, so as Tom Harrington says in comments, you should learn how to use the debugger to iron them out.

Comment: Thanks for response very much! However it doesn't changed a lot, because it wouldn't work if it doesn't declared correctly :( 
I mean DATA TYPE such as managedObjectContext, NSPersistent... the is a place only for one type :) Sometimes it is difficult to allocate the error even with debugger because it shows "nil" values everywhere and ASSEMBLER :) 

Simpler to write .ASM code :D